# How to save a txt file using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

Given this method :

```
public void OutputWrite (BigInteger[] EncryptCodes) throws FileNotFoundException{

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);  
    chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

    String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

    PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new File(path+"EncryptedMessage.txt"));

    for (int i = 0; i <EncryptCodes.length; i++) { 
        file.write(EncryptCodes[i]+ " \r\n");     
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Ignoring the variable names, what this method does is writes data of `EncryptCodes` in the txt file generated inside the project folder called `EncryptedMessage.txt`.

What I need is a method to save that txt file instead of in the project folder , to be saved in a location specified by the user during running (Opens a Save As Dialog Box). I think it can be done by JFilechooser, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a separate method for getting the save location like so:

```
private File getSaveLocation() {
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);  
   int result = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);

   if (result == chooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
      return chooser.getSelectedFile();
   } else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

and then use the result as an argument to the overloaded `File` constructor that takes a parent/directory argument:

```
public void writeOutput(File saveLocation, BigInteger[] EncryptCodes)
                 throws FileNotFoundException {

   PrintWriter file = 
        new PrintWriter(new File(saveLocation, "EncryptedMessage.txt"));
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes.. perfect, but the phrase "this" presents an error.
method showSaveDialog in class JFileChooser cannot be applied to given types;
  required: Component
  found: RSAEncryption
  reason: actual argument RSAEncryption cannot be converted to Component by method invocation conversion
----

Comment: Ok, you need a `JFrame` argument there. If you're only using the `JFileChooser` in a console app, you can simply use `null` here.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new File(filePathChosenByUser + "EncryptedMessage.txt"));
```

Comment: the file path should be choosen by user during runtime

Comment: well, then you'll have to fill `filePathChosenByUser` at runtime?

Comment: If i understood you correctly, You need the user to actually write the path when its asked for, what i need is a Dialog box to open at run time, and for the user to select the directory

Comment: I am pretty sure if you implement an explorer it will be able to return the chosen path as string.

Comment: so were back to the question.. how do i do that ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I missunderstood your question :S
Well, at least you have a solution now :)