# There is no existence of the saved file.How to do that?

Tags: java, file-io

while i am trying to save the file its not working but for making folders it works. what should i do ? i am new in java also. plz help

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{   
    if(ae.getSource()==save)
    {
        JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save");    

        int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(parentFrame);

        if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it print in "Save as file" ?

Comment: What are you seeing? in what way is it not working?

Comment: *"plz help"*  Please spell words properly.

Comment: oh that was for lazyness. sorry. i will correct from next time. please perdon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose a file but don't create it write anything to it. The file will not be created until you actually create it or write something to it, for example with

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileToSave);
writer.write("Hello!");
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the file you want to save as a `File`.
Then, write it to a new directory using `BufferedWriter` to a new directory.

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(aComponent); //parent component to JFileChooser
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { //OK button pressed by user
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile(); //get File selected by user
        o = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); //use its name
        //write things here
        o.flush();
        o.close();
}
```

Look at [How to save file using JFileChooser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589386/how-to-save-file-using-jfilechooser-in-java) and [How to save a txt file using JFileChooser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905298/how-to-save-a-txt-file-using-jfilechooser)

Comment: it has worked. thnk u.. but the text i am writing that is not showed in the save file.....